# What version of angular material i can use on angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been installed angular material on my angular project, but when I run the project I get this error.

```
ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/Corandus/code/angular/webapp_2/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/Corandus/code/angular/webapp_2/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/Corandus/code/angular/webapp_2/src/app/app.module.ts
```

and my version of angular, what I use:

```
@angular/animations: 4.4.7
@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/common: 4.4.7
@angular/compiler: 4.4.7
@angular/core: 4.4.7
@angular/forms: 4.4.7
@angular/http: 4.4.7
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.7
@angular/router: 4.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.1.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.7
@angular/language-service: 4.4.7
```

what version of animation, material, and CDK do I need to use angular material on angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

The major versions of animation, material and cdk packages should match the major version of other @angular packages in your dependencies.

But `@angular/material` exists from Angular 5 as a released package.

The following package should work `@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12` BUT it is a beta version, you should not use in production.

The best think to do is to upgrade to Angular 5 using the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/).